# accept value from one div's fields value only from multiple div's field value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two div while submitting value by clicking the submit button so the value should accept from the only div only not other div. if anyone tries to fill all the div's fields value then show the alert message you can either fill div first value or div second value only.
Here is a demo.

```js
function draftSave() {
alert('hello');

}
```

```html
<div id = "one">
<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="text1" id="text1" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('text1')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="text2" id="text2" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('text2')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>
</div>
<div id = "two">
<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="div2_text1" id="div2_text1" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('div2_text1')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

<textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="div2_text2" id="div2_text2" required maxlength="3500" onKeyup="textareacount3500_characters('div2_text2')" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" name="step5" id="step5" onclick="draftSave()">Draft Save</a>
```

You can see, there is two different div but have to accept only anyone div's fields value. if the user trying to fill both div's values & submitting then should receive an alert message you can fill only anyone div fields value

Comment: So in short you only want two textarea (one div) to be filled and NOT both divs ?

Comment: in one div can be multiple textarea, I wanted only one div can be accept to submit the value if user trying to submit both div same time so should receive error message.

Answer (score 1):

Hers one way to do it...

```js
function draftSave() {
  var one = ""
  document.querySelectorAll('#one > textarea').forEach(el => {
    one += el.value;
  })


  var two = ""
  document.querySelectorAll('#two > textarea').forEach(el => {
    two += el.value;
  })

  if (one !== "" && two !== "") {
    console.clear();
    console.log("alert both rows are filled")
  }else {
  console.clear();
  console.log("submited: " + one + two);
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="one">row1
  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="text1" id="text1" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="text2" id="text2" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>
</div>
<div id="two">row2
  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="div2_text1" id="div2_text1" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>

  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control checking-length" name="div2_text2" id="div2_text2" required maxlength="3500" placeholder="Your answer.."></textarea>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" name="step5" id="step5" onclick="draftSave()">Draft Save</a>
```